# What libraries to use for writing a GWT HTML5 Web Application

Tags: html, gwt

Can someone tell me what libraries I should use to successfully write a smartphone (Mainly Android, iPhone) HTML5 GWT application.  I have seen a number of libraries such as gwt-mobile-webkit and PhoneGap amongst others but am unsure what to use.

I want features such as local storage and I want the application to work offline if possible.

Has anyone had experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects like

- gwt-mobile-toolkit
- [MGWT](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/)

help you optimize your HTML5 layout for mobile devices.
I have tried gwt-mobile-toolkit first but finally swiched over to MGWT because it has good integration with the design patterns of GWT (places and activities).
LocalStorage works without any additional requirements with GWT. For offline, you need to write a manifest file, but I dont have any experience there.

PhoneGap on the other hand, is a javascript library that you will need when you need to access the hardware that is present on the mobile devices. It allows you to access hardware like e.g. GPS or a native beep. So the functionality provided by the phonegap project is completely different. There is a [wrapper project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) for GWT around phonegap too.